# Redirect WooCommerce checkout to cart

Tags: plugin-development, woocommerce-offtopic, redirect

how can I redirect customers to cart page when they click on checkout link?

I found many tutorials to redirect in the opposite sense (cart to checkout) but nothing for my purposes...

Comment: ..But earlier or later your customer should be able to checkout ..or (?) am I missing somehting?

Comment: In fact, in certain situations, I would like to completely disable the ability to checkout. I managed not to show the checkout button in the cart, now I would like to redirect every link to checkout to the cart, is it possible?